# flutter hot reload other pages

Tags: flutter, dart, hot-reload

I am beginner of flutter.
Text (printA ())
and
PrintA () {print ("A"); retuen "A";}
are executed on page A of Flutter, and "A" is displayed in the console after hot reloading. Then navigate to page B and print "B" to the console as well. At this time, if I hot reload, not only "B" but also "A" will be displayed on the console. If I repeat the screen navigation, the number of A and B displayed on the console will continue to increase with one hot reload. What is the reason for this?

```dart
class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  const WordPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("PageA"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(printA()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

printA() {
  print("A");
  return "A";
}
```

[image]
Also, if I just make a screen navigate in the emulator without hot reloading, only "A" on page A and only "B" on page B will be displayed on the console as usual.  and I use m1 mac.

Comment: If you got your answer, consider marking it an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A widget that manages a set of child widgets with a stack discipline.
>
> Many apps have a navigator near the top of their widget hierarchy in
> order to display their logical history using an Overlay with the most
> recently visited pages visually on top of the older pages. Using this
> pattern lets the navigator visually transition from one page to
> another by moving the widgets around in the overlay. Similarly, the
> navigator can be used to show a dialog by positioning the dialog
> widget above the current page.

This is from the doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html your new page 'B' is just above the previous page 'A' which was never destroyed. And hot reload is causing the build method of page 'A' run again and you get 'A' printed.